# Android resource linking failed on build APK

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

i tried to create an app widget.. i can run the widget in emulator.. but i cann't build it as apk file

Below is the error

```
Android resource linking failed 
Output:
F:\me\Workspace\example\base\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\
debugFeature\processDebugFeatureManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:102: 
error: resource xml/ptcwidget_info (aka com.example.app:xml/widget_info) 
not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

but this widget_info.xml is under UIModule.. this merged manifest file is not finding xml folder under resources

Comment: try cache invalidate

Comment: tried it.. but failed..

Comment: Maybe that resource is available only in Debug. Please check if one of its parent folders is located INSIDE a "/debug" folder.

Comment: whr i can find the "/debug" folder

Comment: Please make sure that your widget_info.xml is under res/xml @KirubaHaran

Comment: it is under Ui Module res/xml but merged manifest file is looking at app res/xml

Answer (score 0):

Check gradle implementations, if you did add library it can be merge. Or try rename the xml file and sync project with gradle file.Files may be overlapped

Comment: tried renaming it... it's not working.. manifest file is looking for xml folder under app but file is residing under diffrent module